# PHP parser for Java class / code?

Tags: java, php, grammar

I have a Java class (more precisely a jpa entity) that I want to "parse" in PHP. I want to get the fields of that class, the annotations associated with each field, etc.

Is there any PHP tool that can read java source code and "parse" it? I want to avoid re-inventing the wheel with my own custom regex expressions...

Comment: First result in google: http://freshmeat.net/projects/java2php/

Comment: besides having broken download links that seems to be a tool to convert java source code to PHP which is not what I want. I just want to read a .java file, parse it, and then access it's structure like getAllMethods getAllFields, etc. (similar to DOM parsers)

Comment: You seem disatisfied with the proposed solution of using a java library for that. May I ask why ? Or more interresting, what is the purpose of being able to parse a JPA entity ? Depending of the real need the prefered solution could change.

Comment: Mainly because I asked for a PHP tool, so I don't think a fair answer to this bounty is to say "use Java" :) But because this is supposed to be an online code.generator that can only use PHP and where we can upload a java class. I don't think calling java from PHP a nice solution. And I thought someone in the world would have made a tool like this (I had a compilers course long time ago with topics like grammars, AST, etc and this seemed to be a question related to that)

Comment: That is not because you have a web front end in PHP that it is not possible to use whatever is good for the job on the back end. (Many PHP app use MySQL for example and MySQL is not coded in PHP). If the best solution happen to be in JAVA (or Python, Lisp, Erlang, whatever) use network or files to communicate. For an existing API, I'am afraid that most of them would be in JAVA. You can try to find a parser in PHP (should be already difficult), put AVA grammar into it and process the AST. This should be really doable.

Comment: I agree with that point of view @Nicolas but I don't control the production environment so I don't have access to Java there. I can think of other solutions but right now I'm still hoping for a PHP tool to the job, otherwise I'll just use my "hacky" regular expressions

Comment: If the job could be done with regular expression, it's a fine solution. I wonder, if regular expressions are expressive enough to solve the task. If you managed to solve the problem, would you mind to post code excerpts?

Comment: I'd add that after some throughts, the introspection solution using JAVA is more complex than it appear first. (See comments in the response).

Comment: A year or so ago, i invested a weekend to hack a parser generator [LL(1) / recursive descent]. It's not production level and it is probably not quite well documented, but object oriented. In case you'd like to give it a try, I'm happy to forward it to you. Sample lexical and a simple grammar would be included.

Comment: @AlfaTeK Can you clarify, are you working with the binary .class or the source .java? You've mentioned 'source code' **and** 'upload a java class' (which implies compiled)

Comment: @Phil Lello sorry for the confusion. I have access to the source code so that will be easier to "parse" :)

Answer (score 6):

I'd propose to write a small Java app, which compiles/loads the target Java file and finally returns/prints e.g. JSON data generated by calls to Java's introspection API.

This might probably help or provide useful classes: [Introspection Tool for the Java(TM) Platform 1.0](http://www.sun.com/download/products/45dbeb22.xml)

While it doesn't provides an easy readable representation of the signature of a class, [Java's XMLEncoder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html) provides an XML representation of a JavaBean like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <java version="1.0" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder">
 <object class="javax.swing.JFrame">
   <void property="name">
     <string>frame1</string>
   </void>
   <void property="bounds">
     <object class="java.awt.Rectangle">
       <int>0</int>
       <int>0</int>
       <int>200</int>
       <int>200</int>
     </object>
   </void>
   <void property="contentPane">
     <void method="add">
       <object class="javax.swing.JButton">
         <void property="label">
           <string>Hello</string>
         </void>
       </object>
     </void>
   </void>
   <void property="visible">
     <boolean>true</boolean>
   </void>
 </object>
 </java>
```

Additionally, I'd propose to have a look at this [page](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/), which explains [Java's refelection API](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/).

As of this document, a very simple Java program:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

   public class DumpMethods {
      public static void main(String args[])
      {
         try {
            // @see Hint from Nicolas Bousquet below
            Class c = Class.forName(args[0], false, this.getClass().getClassLoader() );
            Method m[] = c.getDeclaredMethods();
            for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++)
            System.out.println(m[i].toString());
         }
         catch (Throwable e) {
            System.err.println(e);
         }
      }
   }
```

applied to the Java's Stack class like this

```
java DumpMethods java.util.Stack
```

generates this textual output:

```
public java.lang.Object java.util.Stack.push(
    java.lang.Object)
   public synchronized 
     java.lang.Object java.util.Stack.pop()
   public synchronized
      java.lang.Object java.util.Stack.peek()
   public boolean java.util.Stack.empty()
   public synchronized 
     int java.util.Stack.search(java.lang.Object
```

)

Any effort to parse Java source code or (more complex) Java bytecode would be several times more complex than using Java to inspect Java.

Moreover, a PHP solution could even fail, if the syntax of Java source code or class files change later on somehow. Thus, from an architectural point of view, using PHP to implement the desired functionality, is not far away from bad style.

Thus, I wonder, that anybody ever tried to - since the Java alternative is straight-forward and clean.

Comment: That's an hack I would like to avoid if I can get a PHP tool for my purpose. Maybe I'm not using the right wording and what I want is not a parser but something else.

Comment: Hm, in my eyes, it's not a hack but the canonical way to solve the problem. I understand, that you'd like to get the signatures of all accessible classes. Don't you? I feel, that writing a parser for JAVA class files is a bigger effort. But I might be wrong, since you don't need to parse all JAVA, but only top level methods. Hm...

Comment: @AlfaTeK Parsing Java in PHP is far more 'hacky' than the proposed solution; Java already understands Java, PHP would need to be taught. If you need help with the Java to do this, I'm sure someone on SO will help.

Comment: I understand I can use Java for this, using reflection and other utilities like that but my question was for a PHP tool to do this. I want to do a kind of code-generator that works online and it seems to me a bad way to achieve this is to call a java program from php or something like that. After my google searches I just thought someone in the world, would have, at least, done some regex expressions in PHP to parse java files :) [which is my current, "hacky", solution]

Comment: Using introspection API is not a good solution neither, as you have to load the class, you'll need to use a sandbox and prevent code from eating all memory, CPU cycles or whatever.

Comment: @Nicolas Bousquet: You need a sandbox to just inspect the class? The lower solution - not the bean-based option - doesn't need an instance. Additionally, the author didn't disclose, if he may trust the provided Java classes.

Comment: Class.forName is used to force load of some JDBC drivers for exemple. Static fields or statement will be executed. Dependant class will be loaded too. So basically the class can do anything java code can do in the limits of what the classloader permit. Even if the author trust the user some problem could occur if the full classpath is not then when trying to load the class. Please see detailled javadoc : http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.ClassLoader)

Comment: But the initialize parameter seems interresting, might still require full classpath to be available for linking. Should be tested.

Answer (score 1):

The neatest solution to this is to invoke [javadoc with a custom doclet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/javadoc/overview.html), as this doesn't need any compilation of the java sources you want to document. To integrate this with PHP, simply call javadoc via exec().

If you'd like me to put together an implementation for you, please provide more details on how you want to access information in PHP (e.g. parsing a text description, arrays, etc) via an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5794575/edit) to the post.

Answer (score 0):

ANTLR (http://www.antlr.org/) might be a good fit. You could probably use it with the Java grammar specification (http://www.antlr.org/grammar/list) to get a syntax tree for your Java code files. Looking around in the Java grammar, I see things like methodDeclaration, fieldDeclaration, and classDeclaration- sounds like what you were looking for.
A quick Google search turned up a PHP runtime for ANTLR, though that site claims to be new and probably "breakage" prone.

Comment: Interesting. Didn't know, that ANTLR output may be executed by non-Java / foreign runtimes.

Answer (score -1):

I am using PHP/Java Bridge

http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/

Comment: That seems to be a way to connect php and java servers, which is not what I want. I want a php tool that can read .java source code and "parse" it, making available nice methods like getallmethods, getallfields, etc, like a dom traversal lib.